# Can I flatMap into other streams with completables?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, flatmap

I have several `completable rx subscriptions` in a stream like this:

```
viewModel?.setupDoorMode().subscribe(onNext: { shouldConnectToDoor in
    if shouldConnectToDoor {
         self.viewModel?.connectAndOpenDoor().subscribe(onCompleted: {
             self.viewModel?.openOrCloseDoor().subscribe().disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
         }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    } else {
         self.viewModel?.openOrCloseDoor().subscribe().disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    }
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I have the feeling that this can be done in a nicer way, like flatMaping the streams into oneanother. But when I try using `flatMap` I get the error `Type '()' cannot conform to 'ObservableConvertibleType'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols`. I'm not too familiar with `rx` to understand that message. Anyway, is there a way to create a more smooth looking stream rather than three `subscriptions` in a row?

Comment: why are you subscribing to some other subject/relay inside the onNext of `setupDoorMode` A rule of thumb is, if you have to subscribe for someother subject inside the onNext block you have messed up the design and there exists much better design to deal with

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Yes, that was exactely what I was asking for. How do I do it the "correct" way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re definitely on the right track thinking about `flatMap` to compose your observables. The thing to note here is that calling `.subscribe()` returns a `Disposable` type and calling `.disposed(by:)` on that disposable returns `Void` aka `()` type. You can't compose `Voids`. You have compose the observables, and THEN you subscribe to the result.

```
guard let viewModel = viewModel else { return }

// Combine the observables
let doorActionObservable = viewModel
    .setupDoorMode()
    .flatMap { /* mind the retain cycle */ shouldConnectToDoor in
        if shouldConnectToDoor {
            return self.viewModel.connectAndOpenDoor()
        } else {
            return self.viewModel.openOrCloseDoor()
        }
    }

// Subscribe to the the resulting observable
doorActionObservable
    .subscribe()
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Nice, thank you so much for helping me out @NikitaKukushkin. One thing though: When ConnectAndOpenDoor has completed, I want openOrCloseDoor to be triggered. How do I incorporate that?

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that. You can either do another `flatMap` after `connectAndOpenDoor()`, or, if your signal can fire multiple times and you really need the `onCompleted` trigger, you can add `.do(onCompleted:)` but then you'll have to subscribe to the inner signal.